# TurboGears 2.3 @validte in two steps

Tags: validation, turbogears2, formencode

I'm using TurboGears 2.3 and working on validating forms with formencode and need some guidance

I have a form which covers 2 different objects. They are a almost the same, but with some difference
When i submit my form, I want to validate 2 things

1. Some basic data
2. Some specific data for the specific object

Here are my schemas:

```
class basicQuestionSchema(Schema):
    questionType = validators.OneOf(['selectQuestion', 'yesNoQuestion', 'amountQuestion'])
    allow_extra_fields = True


class amount_or_yes_no_question_Schema(Schema):
    questionText = validators.NotEmpty()
    product_id_radio = object_exist_by_id(entity=Product, not_empty=True)
    allow_extra_fields = True


class selectQuestionSchema(Schema):
    questionText = validators.NotEmpty()
    product_ids = validators.NotEmpty()
    allow_extra_fields = True
```

And here are my controller's methods:

```
@expose()
@validate(validators=basicQuestionSchema(), error_handler=questionEditError)
def saveQuestion(self,**kw):
    type = kw['questionType']
    if type == 'selectQuestion':
        self.save_select_question(**kw)
    else:
        self.save_amount_or_yes_no_question(**kw)


@validate(validators=selectQuestionSchema(),error_handler=questionEditError)
def save_select_question(self,**kw):
    ...
    Do stuff
    ...



@validate(validators=amount_or_yes_no_question_Schema(),error_handler=questionEditError)
def save_amount_or_yes_no_question(self,**kw):
    ...
    Do other stuff
    ...
```

What I wanted to do was validate twice, with different schemas. This doesn't work, as only the first @validate is validated, and the other are not (maybe ignored)

So, what am i doning wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@validate` is part of the request flow, so when manually calling a controller it is not executed (it is not a standard python decorator, all TG2 decorators actually only register an hook using `tg.hooks` so they are bound to request flow).

What you are trying to achieve should be done during validation phase itself, you can then call `save_select_question` and `save_amount_or_yes_no_question` as plain object methods after validation.

See http://runnable.com/VF_2-W1dWt9_fkPr/conditional-validation-in-turbogears-for-python for a working example of conditional validation.